# How to share picture or text from fragment to Facebook using android studio?

Tags: java, android, facebook

I try to share picture from a fragment in android studio to facebook

..... the application has many of fragments so if i press on "share" the picture in this fragment will share on my Facebook and so on for the rest.

I used Intent to share text but this not work :

```
Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 intent.setType("text/plain");
 intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, desc.getText().toString());
 startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Share with"));
 share(desc.getText().toString());
```

Thanks

Comment: Please be specific what you already did and what you're trying to achieve. And post some relevant code in order to make us understand your question.

Answer (score 3):

try this reference:

: http://simpledeveloper.com/how-to-share-an-image-on-facebook-in-android/
             hope it will help you.if it is working accept my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can try this with the use of facebook sdk.

```
    private void shareFacebook(){

        if (!ShareDialog.canShow(ShareLinkContent.class)) return;

        ShareDialog dialog = new ShareDialog(this);
        ShareLinkContent.Builder builder = new ShareLinkContent.Builder();
        builder.setContentUrl(Uri.parse("FileSharingUrl"));
        builder.setImageUrl(Uri.parse("image url"));
        if (mSharePhotoosUrl) {
            builder.setContentDescription("body description");
        }
        if (mShareCreator) {
            builder.setContentTitle("title if any");
        }
        dialog.show(getActivity(), builder.build());
    }
}
```

Comment: mShareCretor not defined in my app why ?

Comment: msharePhotoosUrl and mShareCreator are boolean values just to check if it is coming empty in my above case.